# WebView disable scrollbars

Tags: webview, uwp, uwp-xaml, scrollviewer

Why can't I disable `WebView`'s scrollbars? 
This is my code

```
<WebView x:Name="Browser" Source="https://m.investing.com/economic-calendar/" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

No scrollbars are disabled. Any ideas how to disable the vertical scroll bars.
The goal is to wrap the `WebView` in a `ScrollViewer` and use `ScrollViewer`'s scroll bars instead.

Answer (score 1):

Solution here:

```
private static string[] SetBodyOverFlowHiddenString = new string[] { @"function SetBodyOverFlowHidden() { document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; } SetBodyOverFlowHidden();" };
    private async void Browser_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await Browser.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", SetBodyOverFlowHiddenString);
        Debug.WriteLine("Loaded");
    }
```

Comment: If you use `eval`, there doesn't seem to be any need to define a function.Just inline code.